# React material UI reset values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI with react.

I can't seem to be able to reset a form on submit without getting errors in the console.

If I have: `<TextField defaultValue={myComment.title} refs="title" />`

On Submit, if I do this: `this.refs.title.setValue('')` I get the following error in the console

> Warning: setValue() method is deprecated. Use the defaultValue property instead.
>         Or use the TextField as a controlled component with the value property.

So I tried to do: `this.refs.title.defaultValue = ''` but that didn't work.

I'm thinking I have to do a handleChange event? But seems very painful to set this up when all I want to do is clear the input field.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, the best way to use this component that can help you to achieve easily what you need (even if its a bit verbose) would be passing an `value` and `onChange` properties to the `TextField`... 
You may handle the `value` on the state from your current component or even pass from parent's components as props..

A simple example:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        name: event.target.value
    })
}


cleanInput() {
    this.setState({
        name: ''
    })
}

<TextField value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: And here I was thinking React/Material UI was going to make my life simpler... ;) ha. Thanks.

Comment: yea.. It may require more typing, but it's worth at the end of day :)

Comment: @AndréJunges what is cleanInput() ?

Comment: @netpoetica it's just a function that I created to reset the name

Comment: This pattern causes a lag for text boxes. Is there any second option? Thanks.

Comment: it depends on how many components you are rerendering based on this state's change.. one thing you can do to not create a new function in each render method is to bind the `handleInputChange` function in your constructor..

Comment: Beware of the transitional warning in react:

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type password to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component....

*******************


Using state on such items can be desperately frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `getInputNode().value=""`

So in you case it will be `this.refs.title.getInputNode().value=""`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for resetting your TextField and Props and States:

```
reset = ()=> {
       var  m = "";
       document.getElementById('h1').value = m;
}
```

It will only reset your textField, and if you want to reset State or Props too then just add `setState()` method in it.

```
reset = ()=> {
           setState({
               firtName: '',
               lastName: ''
             })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this question and I see you can just write:

```
type="reset"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfcrsqy2/

Comment: This question asks about material-ui not vanilla HTML elements

Comment: I know I also use with material-ui and it works there too